# How to list manually created AWS resources and not resources created by CloudFormation templates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to have an AWS Config rule to notify on manual resource creation but ignore resources created by CloudFormation templates.

As a first step, listing all manually created resources would suffice.

Is there any AWS feature I could use to achieve this with minimum effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudFormation uses tags which are reserved for AWS use only, cannot be added by regular users and are [created automatically](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html):

> In addition to any tags you define, AWS CloudFormation automatically creates the following stack-level tags with the prefix aws::
>
> - aws:cloudformation:logical-id
> - aws:cloudformation:stack-id
> - aws:cloudformation:stack-name

You could use AWS Config [required-tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/required-tags.html) to check for the lack of presence of the reserved one(s) and that will give you non-CF created resources.